# How to change local property of fullcalendar in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I want to change `local` propety of `fullcalendar`, 
When I try to set it to `"en-gb"` but It does not work.  Where I'm wrong ?

```
<full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" [header]="{
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
}" local="en-gb" [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [weekends]="calendarWeekends" [events]="calendarEvents"></full-calendar>
```

typescript :

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("calendar", { static: false })
  calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the template
  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
  calendarWeekends = true;
  calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [{ title: "Event Now", start: new Date() }];
}
```

Based on `"en-gb"` the first day of week is **Monday**.

**[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf2v4r)**

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale here you have all the information. Have you tried with `calendar.setOption('locale', 'pt-br');` ?

Comment: @Jotan- How can I do that in Angular based on Stackblitz example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889727/how-to-use-locale-in-fullcalendar-in-angular-7 here is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting locale of calendar object like below.

```
import enGbLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/en-gb';

  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.calendarComponent.calendar.setOption('locale', enGbLocale);
    })
  }
```

Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhajcg

Doc Reference is here - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

Comment: Property 'calendar' is private and only accessible within class 'FullCalendarComponent'